# Iterating over arrays in haskell

Tags: arrays, haskell, iteration

My problem is that I need to iterate over array and calculate some value depend on every element. I was looking for some fold-like function for arrays, but standard library seems to be very useless with arrays. Or i'm missing something?

The other solution may be 'binding' array to a list. Binding mean that I don't want to copy that array. Is this possible?

Btw, its all about plain Array.

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at [Data.Foldable](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Foldable.html). It defines a type class that does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Using [`Data.Foldable`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.10.2/html/libraries/base/Data-Foldable.html) you can `foldr`/`foldl` an `Array` just like you can a list.

Another option is that you can convert the `Array` back into a list with `elems`, and then `foldr` or `foldl` over the list.

Comment: Unfortunately this array is pretty big, so it takes too long to use elems.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of array type are you using? You may be able to just foldM over the index space.

Or use one of the array libraries that directly support folds (uvector).